# Getting "Failed To load the library" error when calling IEDriverServer

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm testing our application using Selenium WebDriver 2.25 on different versions of Windows Explorer, which means running the test on different machines.

While testing the application with IE 8 works fine, I get an odd error when trying to run the test on the workstation with IE7. It's running Windows XP Service Pack 2 loaded with Java 6. When I try to run the IEDriverServer_Win32 executable, I get the following error:

```
Failed to load the library from temp directory: C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I tried the same thing with the 2.32 version of the IE Driver Server and got the exact same error, so upgrading would not necessarily fix this. As to the permission issue, well, yes, I did suspect that as a cause, but what permissions where? Any assistance with that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

IEDriverServer.exe is architected as a small, simple executable file that has a .dll with the real code for the IE driver embedded as a resource inside the .exe. To make use of this .dll, the executable has to extract the .dll somewhere so it can call the Windows `LoadLibrary` API to load and subsequently execute the code of the .dll. By default, that extraction is done into the temp directory. Without generating a log file to look into the issue, we can surmise that the .dll either isn't getting extracted properly, or once extracted, that the call to `LoadLibrary` failed.

Fortunately, the IE driver provides a workaround for this issue. If you pass `--extract-path="path\to\extract\dll\to"` as a command-line argument to IEDriverServer.exe, you will be able to explicitly specify which directory to use for the extraction. See the documentation for your language bindings to see how to have this command-line argument passed programmatically.

For instance, making this work for Java, the code would look like the following:

```
// WARNING: Entirely untested code below! Was written from memory without
// the benefit of an IDE. May not work correctly or even compile without
// modification.
// Assume "location" is a properly instantiated java.io.File containing
// the location of IEDriverServer.exe.
InternetExplorerDriverService service = new InternetExplorerDriverService.Builder()
    .withExtractPath(location)
    .build();
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(service);
```

Another alternative might be to manually launch IEDriverServer.exe, and use your language bindings' `RemoteWebDriver` class to connect to it. That means you're responsible for the lifetime of the executable process, but it might be a way for you to get the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. That is certainly a step closer. Unfortunately, I cannot find any reference on how to set the value programmatically. The InternetExplorerDriver class in the Selenium WebDriver API has the option of defining Capabilities, but setting the extract path does not seem to be one of them.

Comment: Updated to include a Java example.

Comment: Unfortunately, the InternetExplorerDriverService  class in Selenium 2.25 does not seem to support the Builder() method.

Comment: And 2.25 is months old. The most recent release is 2.32. You really should be using a more recent release.

Comment: I tried using a later version of Selenium WebDriver, but encountered a problem with selecting fields that were scrolled out of sight, something that wasn't happening with 2.25. Upgrading would just trade one problem for a greater one.

Comment: So have you submitted a bug report (with, and this is important, HTML page to test against)? Or better still, a pull request with the fix for your scrolling issue? I'm not sure I understand how this answer does not answer your question. If the answer requires a later version than you're using, and you're unwilling to use that version (or unwilling to help fix the problems that discourage you from using it), that's not a problem with the answer, right?

Comment: Additionally, you could use 2.25 of IEDriverServer.exe and a later language binding. Not that I'd recommend it, but it might be an option.

Comment: I haven't bothered reporting the issue because, as I mentioned, the application (and the development environment it's on) is on an isolated network, so providing a HTML page to test against is not an option. If the only solution to this issue is "use a later version" and doing so breaks the application in other greater ways, then I guess there isn't a solution. Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had a similar problem, where it couldn't extract to the temp directory, what I did was I went into the folder where IEDriver extracts the DLL, and deleted everything in that folder related to Selenium.

So for me it was C:\Users\usnm\AppData\Local\Temp, and there were a lot of files like webdriver_blahblah120398405.tmp, and a lot of folders similarly named.  When I removed them all, my program started working again.  So for you it'd be C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp

Of course our errors are slightly different (and I'm using Selenium 2.33).  My error was "failed to extract", not "failed to load"

Comment: Thanks. I ended up having the system administrator make sure the test account had access to the temporary folder. A bit of a kludge, but it works for what we're doing.

Answer (score 0):

In some systems antivirus or other protection software prevent running exe files or in this case loading dll library from temp folder.

when starting your selenium node add an extra parameter and specify extract path to current dir (make sure current dir is writable by your user and does not require elevated privileges). For example if your IEDriverServer.exe is located in C:\node then

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role node ..... -Dwebdriver.ie.driver.extractpath=C:\node
```

this should fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Following the answer 2, this is the exact way to do it:

```
File extractPath=new File("c://your//file//todllextracts");
InternetExplorerDriverService service = new InternetExplorerDriverService.Builder().withExtractPath(extractPath).build();

driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(service);
```